# Can't update module astropy in an environment

Tags: python, conda, astropy, virtual-environment

I'm running Anaconda with an environment `phd`, and I'm trying to update `astropy` to the current version (`5.0.4`, same as in my `base` environment).

```
>>> conda activate phd
>>> python
Python 3.7.1 (default, Oct 28 2018, 08:39:03) [MSC v.1912 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import astropy
>>> print(astropy.__version__)
4.3.1
```

In the base environment, I get

```
>>> python
Python 3.9.12 (main, Apr  4 2022, 05:22:27) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda,
Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import astropy
>>> print(astropy.__version__)
5.0.4
>>>
```

I've tried `conda upgrade astropy` from within `phd`, and `conda update --name phd astropy`, both of which return

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.

Retrieving notices: ...working... done
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It might be that you have some other package(s) installed that have an older version of astropy pinned as a dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Python 3.7 is not supported.** Unless a Python package is designated as `noarch` - `astropy` is not -, a build must be made for each Python version. A maintainer of the Conda Forge `astropy` feedstock [dropped support for Python 3.7 in Nov. 2022](https://github.com/conda-forge/astropy-feedstock/commit/295d6740edba6ac211a5493460ad940d0273866e#diff-f3725a55bf339595bf865fec73bda8ac99f283b0810c205442021f29c06eea9aR24). This was consistent with [the documented requirements of `astropy`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/install.html#requirements), that show version 5+ requiring Python 3.8+.

If you would like to use the newer versions of `astropy` then create a new environment with a more recent version of Python. I would not recommend upgrading Python in-place, since most packages will have to be replaced anyway.